# How to change height of country_picker?

Tags: flutter

I am using country_picker for drop-down-menu.

And I need to reduce height of this menu. How can I do this?

And how to get border to showCountryPicker?

[This is what I want](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dDq5b.png)

[And this what I get](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YAZZn.png)

I tried to add bottomSheetHeight, but it hides my bottom buttons.

And without bottomSheetHeigh the drop-down-menu is in full screen mode

This is my code:

```
Expanded(
            child: Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(left: 12, right: 12),
              child: TextFormField(
                controller: _country,
                readOnly: true,
                onTap: () {
                  showCountryPicker(
                    context: context,
                    showWorldWide: false,
                    showPhoneCode: false,
                    showSearch: false,
                    countryListTheme: CountryListThemeData(
                      backgroundColor: AppColors.backgroundColor,
                      borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(8),
                      bottomSheetHeight: 380,
                      flagSize: 0,
                      textStyle: TextStyle(
                        color: AppColors.grayA0A0A0,
                        fontSize: 18,
                        height: 2.0
                      )
                    ),
                    onSelect: (Country country) {
                      log(country.toString());
                    }
                  );
                },
                decoration: InputDecoration(
                  border: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10.0),
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 0)),
                  focusedBorder: OutlineInputBorder(
                    borderSide: const BorderSide(width: 1, color: AppColors.darkGray),
                    borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(10)),
                  hintText: "Choose a country",
                  hintStyle: const TextStyle(
                      color: AppColors.grayA0A0A0, fontWeight: FontWeight.w500),
                  filled: true,
                  fillColor: AppColors.lightDark,
                  contentPadding:
                      const EdgeInsets.only(left: 8, bottom: 20, top: 20),
                  prefixIcon: InkWell(
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/icons/Country.svg",
                      color: AppColors.grayA0A0A0,
                      height: 14,
                      width: 18,
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    ),
                  ),
                  suffixIcon: InkWell(
                    child: SvgPicture.asset(
                      "assets/icons/arrow_down.svg",
                      color: AppColors.grayA0A0A0,
                      height: 14,
                      width: 18,
                      fit: BoxFit.scaleDown,
                    ),
                  )
                ),
              ),
            ),
          ),
```

Comment: you are using expanded that means it'll expand from every side you are try giving the width and height

Comment: @LuckyTrail, I tried to remove Expanded widget, but it didn't work. ShowCountryPicker just comes from the bottom and overlay all my ui. How can I remove this overlay?

Answer (score 0):

```
Row(
            children: <Widget>[
              Expanded(
                flex: 1,
                //SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                child: CountryPicker(
                  dense: true,
                  showFlag: false, //displays flag, true by default
                  showDialingCode:
                      true, //displays dialing code, false by default
                  showName: true, //displays country name, true by default
                  showCurrency: false, //eg. 'British pound'
                  showCurrencyISO: false,
                  onChanged: (Country country) {
                    setState(() => _selected = country);
                    print(country.dialingCode);
                    countryCode = country.dialingCode;
                  },
                  selectedCountry: _selected,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                //SizedBox(height: 20.0),
                child: TextFormField(
                  decoration: InputDecoration(
                    labelText: 'Mobile no.',
                    border: OutlineInputBorder(),
                  ),
                  validator: (val) => val.length != 10
                      ? 'Enter a mobile number of 10 digits'
                      : null,
                  onChanged: (val) {
                    setState(() => phone = val);
                    phoneno = phone;
                  },
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
```